# Jersey REST (GET) throwing MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml

Tags: rest, jersey-client, media-type

I have developed a REST service (GET) using Jersey. I want to return the response as application/xml. 
I get an exception when I annotate the following whereas when I change it to MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, service works and returns the response as JSON.
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml

Many blogs have advised to include a dependency to **jersey-media-jaxb** but I have another service which is successfully returning XML response without that dependency. The only difference is that service is a POST end-point whereas the one which is currently not working is a GET end-point.

Comment: You could use "Postman" and change types of request to check the problem, and you could post the excerpt of the code?

Comment: Is the model annotated with `@XmlRootElement`? And does the model class have a no-arg constructor? Both are required

Comment: Hi @Paul Samsotha, I was provided with a XSD file and when I generated model class out of them, they contain only the following annotations.        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "getCustomerResponse", propOrder = {
    "_return"
})  There is NO XmlRootElement

Comment: Try to add it and see what happens. Is there a JAXBContext generated?

Comment: I think you might need to create a ContextResolver for the JAXBContext if you don't want to have to add `@XmlRootElement` to all the classes. I'm not sure though. The annotation might be required.

Answer (score 0):

If the  annotation @XmlRootElement(name = "name") not mentioned in your class, try to add it. it worked for me!